# Does vtk mesh generation change coordinates?

Tags: vtk, vertex

I converted nifti file to vtk using python-implemented vtk. The main function was vtkMarchingCubes.

```
contour=vtk.vtkMarchingCubes()
```

The result vtk meshes have proper shape but their locations seem changed. 
For example, when I load them with the pial surface made from exactly the same nifti image using different pipelines (freesurfer) in the same scene, the result is like below.

Does vtk converting of nifti changes the coordinate of vertices or somehow 'reset' them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VTK's MarchingCubes filter should produce triangles in the same coordinate system as the volume.  The only issue is that the Nifti image also includes a coordinate system of the image, and VTK is probably not correctly using it.  I'd guess there's a transform in the Nifti that VTK isn't properly using.

Try using either Slicer (slicer.org) or ITK-Snap (itksnap.org).  They do better at maintaining coordinate systems for medical images.

Comment: Since I have to make all things to bash script (and Python), I am forced to use VTK. I found  reader.GetQFormMatrix() in vtkNIFTIImageReader, and it has some offsets. Should I set some option to vtkPolyDataWriter?

Comment: I'm glad you have it figure out.  If you ever need it, Slicer can be scripted in Python.  It doesn't have a loadable module, so you have to run Slicer as s command line program, but you can feed it a python script to do whatever processing and then write out there results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, VTK changes the coordinate when read nifti.

-get Q-matrix using GetQFormMatrix() 
-transform coordinate using vtkTransform()
is reqiured.